# Optionally try to load <script> based on environment

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I have an app that's a website, Chrome extension, and PhoneGap / Cordova Android app all based on the same codebase.

I'd like the browser to only try and fetch `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` when my app is wrapped as a PhoneGap app so that it doesn't show a 404 in the console on the website and extension, however I'm not sure how I could specify a conditional like that around a `<script>` tag in HTML, or how I would detect the environment.

I can check if I'm in a PhoneGap environment with `if !!window.cordova` however I don't think I'd have access to that until I include the `cordova.js` script. So it's a chicken-and-egg scenario.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, then you could use `$.getScript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module loader will do this kind of thing for you. Going forward, I would recommend using [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) for this purpose as it's a modern module loader that supports all the glorious features of ES6, if you're into that kind of thing.

An alternative is [RequireJS](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs), for which there is a lightweight drop-in replacement called Almond, which might suit your requirements better given that it's tiny and you only need it to load a single module. You might want to start with RequireJS and then swap it out with Almond when everything's working fine.

With the RequireJS/Almond syntax your conditional script loader would look something like this. Note that because the script is loaded asynchronously, code that uses the script will need to be executed inside the require() callback that fires after the script has loaded:

```
if (window.shouldLoadCordovaScript) {
    // Requiring 'cordova' fetches ./cordova.js
    require(['cordova'], function (cordova) {
        // code that uses cordova
    });
}
```

You might still run into some hurdles if the Cordova script doesn't properly support asynchronous module loading, or it has support for the CommonJS environment but not AMD, etc, in which case you'll need to either prebundle a version with an AMD wrapper, or "shim" it (see the RequireJS docs), which can get a bit messy.